# Pyspark StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY Disk Location for Persist

Tags: pyspark

If I have multiple storage volumes mounted on my jupyter notebook, how do I specify which one should be used when I use df.persist(StorageLevel.DiskOnly)
I want to ensure that persist using larger disk and not the smaller one.

In another words how to specify disk location for df.persist() using pyspark.

I tried to search however could not find the answer in pyspark documentation